# Utility to integrate iTunes with Amazon

Tags: itunes, books, utilities

> Is there any utility or script that integrates with iTunes and helps me organize my libraries by doing lookups on large databases such as Amazon?

For example:

- downloading track names from Amazon
- downloading CD covers from Amazon
- downloading book categories from Amazon (this one especially would be useful)

Or in general, at least a "look it up on Amazon" script would be great.

Answer (score 1):

[Meta X](http://www.kerstetter.net/index.php/projects/software/metax) works great for me for movies, not sure if you're looking for that though since you just mention music and books.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this application - [SuperSync](http://www.supersync.com/) - mentioned on MacWorld. It specifically mentions that it uses Amazon (among other sources) although I'm not sure if it's truly integrated with iTunes or works directly on the media files. There is a demo version available if you want to try it out.

Cheers,

Maurice